# Turn off escaping in parameter for MySQL query in Excel 2010

Tags: mysql, excel, parameters, odbc

I'm using Excel 2010 along with an ODBC connector to pull data from a MySQL database.

I only want to pull certain records based on a list of usernames.

I've got the list of logins into a cell properly formatted for

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE login IN (?)
```

with the parameter pointing to a cell containing a list of the form (constructed from a column using a custom concatenation function):

'login1','login2',...'loginN'

However, when I run the query I get 0 rows returned; playing around with it it appears that Excel is escaping the single quotes so the query as sent to the MySQL server is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE login IN (\'login1\',\'login2\',...\'loginN\')
```

...which matches nothing.

Is there any way to prevent the escaping, or another approach to the "SELECT...WHERE IN" query that will work?

Comment: You can execute against a Jet/ACE connection with in-line connection to MySql, which means you can select from sheets and ranges in Excel. You can also use ADO and GetString with Excel to create a list.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm not sure you understand my question though. I'm not trying to query from data in Excel, I'm trying to construct a cell that can be used as a parameter for "SELECT WHERE IN"; copy-pasting the value from my cell into a MySQL query works as expected, but when Excel constructs the query from the cell contents it escapes the single quotes, rendering the query ineffective.

Comment: You say "constructed from a column using a custom concatenation function" I am suggesting you skip the custom function and either use ADO to get the list or refer to the list as an ado table. I should add that I do not get any escape character when I test in Excel VBA, so it is not impossible that something is coming from the function.

Comment: Imagine I've never used ADO before :)